# Wiring issue need help

Tags: electrical, receptacle, outdoor

Ok...so I have an electrical issue that I am having some difficulty figuring out.  I have 3 lights in the perimeter of my property with 2 being on the problem feed.  The 1 light on the other side of the property works great with the switch.  So from the supply drop there are 2 lights on a switch and an outlet that is always on.  There are 4 wires red, white, black, ground.  At the switch there are 3....ground, black white with white being hot.

When switch is on white at the switch and drop are hot...black and red show no voltage.

When the switch is off...the black at the drop now shows voltage with white still hot and the red still does not show voltage.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you using to test for voltage?

Comment: Voltmeter...failed to mention the feed went to an outlet and then from the outlet is where the split went to separate the lights and continuous supply for the other outlet.  The voltmeter read 120 on lines listing as hot.